# Migrating database in spring application

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

In spring integrated hibernated application,I need to change the database from sql server to oracle without code change ?

Comment: Are you talking about migrating the data or just changing the datasource?

Comment: Yes changing the database from oracle to mysql without any change in the code how to do that and dialect is fine is there any answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to change the datasource

have a look at the documentation here [Spring Documentation for Oracle JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/orcl.datasource.html)

- You need to change your datasource that you use to point to Oracle.
- Import the JDBC dependency for the Oracle JDBC connector as a dependency
- Configure Hibernate to use the correct dialect
  e.g. `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Don't know how you configure your environment, but that should get you started.